# Rails callback changed attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I've got a before_save callback in my User model :

```
before_save :notify_management, :if => lambda { |u| u.approved }
```

The goal of this was when people change approved from `false` to `true` that the management be notified. However once they change to true, and make any kind change on User model, this one gets invoked and I don't want that. I want it to invoke only when changing from `non true` (nil or false) value to `true`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first lets look at what your code actually does,

You are triggering the before_save callback so any time a record is created or updated  `:notify_management` will be called. With the added conditional, `:notify_management` is called whenever a record is saved AND the users approved attribute is `true` (anything except `false` or `nil`).

You want to only do it if the attribute is changed from false to true. So use:

```
before_save :notify_management, :if => lambda { |u| u.approved && u.approved_changed? }
```

By adding the second part, it will only trigger if that attribute has changed (from false=>true or true=>false) and combine it with what you already had it will only trigger when the value changed from false=>true

Hope this helps.